# Did Jews have to support freeing Aaron Mostofsky

Tags: halacha, modern-times, current-events, pidyon-shvuyim-prisoners

According to this [article](https://www.cnn.com/2022/05/06/politics/mostofsky-son-of-new-york-judge-rioter-caveman-sentenced/index.html) one of the people convicted of crimes for breaching the US Capitol on January 6th, 2021 and sentenced to prison is an Orthodox Jew. Would the mitzvah of Pidyon Shvuyim apply here and did Jews have to try and support freeing him while he was serving out his sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mitzva of pidyon shvuyim is normally understood for prisoners unjustly imprisoned, often risking their lives or (in the case of women) poor treatment. It is not meant for prisoners who were legally detained following acts contravening *dina d'malkhuta* (the law of the land) as ruled by a court of law. Otherwise you could ask the question regarding any Jewish prisoner.

dinonline ([here](https://dinonline.org/2010/06/12/modern-day-pidyon-shvuyim/)) indeed writes that

> **The concept of modern imprisonment would not fall under the category of pidyon shvuyim, because it does not pose a threat to the captive’s
> life**, which was the case in Chazal’s conception of pidyon shvuyim.
> This makes a practical difference for the order in which tzedakah
> should be allocated, in which pidyon shvuyim tops the list. However,
> it still remains an important mitzvah to help Jews in such dire need
> [etc.]

The Aruch Hashulchan writes similarly (YD 252:1)

> **And all this was in earlier times**, and even nowadays in far flung
> wildernesses such as Asia and Africa, where bandits fall upon
> travelers and take them into captivity to the point where it is
> necessary to redeem them with large sums of money, as is known from
> the caravans that travel in the western wilderness

The issue is more complicated however and R Gil Student brings an interesting survey of sources [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2021/10/pidyon-shevuyim-for-someone-guilty/), R Yair Hoffman does the same [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/2184800/mi-kaamcha-yisroel-on-a-pidyon-shvuyim-plus-a-halachic-analysis.html) incl. a famous story from R Moshe Feinstein who refused to help free a drug dealer.

**Ultimately, it might turn out to be a highly personal judgement depending on the circumstances of incarceration (e.g., risk of violence), whether due process was held, the danger to others presented by the prisoner, etc.**

Comment: Also even if it theoretically applies, there are many shevuyim in Gaza who are in real danger and would take priority

Comment: This is correct if there was a choice to be made, unfortunately in Gaza there is no real path individuals can take to contribute to rescuing the captives. Halevai there was

Comment: The average person can't do much about Mostofsky either.  For Americans, lobbying politicians is probably the most effective thing most people can do in either case.

Comment: As in many places in Aruch Hashulchan, that comment sounds like the kind of thing either he had to do for fear of the local government, or the censors did for him. "Of course it could not apply here in our law-abiding country!" (Tzarist Russia)